# radio button align with text

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get my gender button to align with my radio image buttons this is  the codes have so far. It gives me the text above the button. Thank you in advance

```html
<div class="genderalign">
    <p>Choose:</p>
    <input type="radio" name="option" value="1" id="choose-1" />
    <label for="choose-1">
        <img src="/images/femaleC.png" />
    </label>

    <input type="radio" name="option" value="2" id="choose-2" />
    <label for="choose-2">
        <img src="/images/maleC.png" />
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Your html seems to be invalid, please could you edit your question with your current css and fixed html

Comment: hi this is my current codes in my html file and it seems to be working on my end

Comment: please validate it and you will see your error - it may work fine but that will be thew browser trying to correct your error automatically, if you leave it like that then different browsers may have different results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've corrected the misplaced `</div>` so your HTML is now like this.

Then just apply flexbox

```css
.genderalign {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="genderalign">
    <p>Choose:</p>
    <input type="radio" name="option" value="1" id="choose-1" />
    <label for="choose-1">
    <img src="/images/femaleC.png"/>
   </label>

    <input type="radio" name="option" value="2" id="choose-2" />
    <label for="choose-2">
    <img src="/images/maleC.png" />
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```